# How can I fix a MySQL Error, Not allowed to return a result set from a function

Tags: mysql, function

```
CREATE FUNCTION `ConvertDate`(StringDate varchar(15))
RETURNS datetime
BEGIN
    declare CDATE varchar(10);
    SET CDATE = StringDate;
    select str_to_date(CDATE,'%Y%m%d %h%i');
    RETURN CDATE;
END
```

I get an error:

> Error Code: 1415 Not allowed to return a result set from a function

How can I fix this Error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your `SELECT` statement has no `INTO` clause, so it attempts to return the result set from the function. You could alter that to:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CDATE,'%Y%m%d %h%i') INTO CDATE;
```

But you might as well do all the computation in the `RETURN` statement:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `ConvertDate2`(StringDate varchar(15))
RETURNS datetime
RETURN STR_TO_DATE(StringDate,'%Y%m%d %h%i');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should

```
Select INTO cdate...
```

or don't bother with the select and

```
set cdate = str_to_date..
```

BUT Unless this is a very simplified version of your actual function I don's see the point of the function.